# operating over the Union type in Julia

Tags: methods, types, julia, dispatch, union-types

In Julia, the `isimmutable` function supposedly can tell you when an object is immutable. It doesn't work for types, however, so I wanted to write a version of this for types. Based on advice I found elsewhere, a good start would be this:

```
isimmtype(t::Type) = error("Type $t has not defined isimmtype")
isimmtype(t::DataType) = begin
    if !t.isconcretetype
        error("Abstract types are neither immutable nor mutable")
    else 
        return !t.mutable
    end
end
```

This is useful, and answers the questions for many but not all types. The failures fall into two categories that I've noticed so far:

1. **Types for which this pattern works but that give the wrong answer relative to Julia documentation.** The only examples I've found are **String** and **Symbol**, both of which are supposedly immutable but return false. There are bug reports out there about this, so my knee-jerk solution is to just write methods for these types explicitly overriding the 
   behavior
2. **Types for which this pattern fails.** These include `Union` and `UnionAll` types. Both appear to have easy solutions. In the case of `UnionAll`, we can test against a reification of the type using the type-variable's upper-bound. For a `Union{A,B}`, we can compare the mutability of types `A` and `B` and deduce the mutability of the union.

I went ahead and wrote these solutions into what I think it a reasonable trait-like syntax, and it partly works:

```
"""
    Mutability
The Mutability type is an abstract trait type with children Mutable, Immutable,
and UnknownMutability.
"""
abstract type Mutability end
struct Mutable <: Mutability end
struct Immutable <: Mutability end
struct UnknownMutability <: Mutability end
const MUT_TYPE = Mutable()
const IMM_TYPE = Immutable()
const UNK_TYPE = UnknownMutability()

"""
    mutability(obj)
Yields an object of type Mutable, Immutable, or UnknownMutability depending on
whether the given type object is mutable, immutable, or unknown.
"""
mutability(T::Type) = UNK_TYPE
isimmtype(T::Type) = IMM_TYPE === mutability(T)

mutability(T::DataType) = begin
    if !T.isconcretetype
        return UNK_TYPE
    elseif T.mutable
        return MUT_TYPE
    else
        return IMM_TYPE
    end
end
mutability(::Core.TypeofBottom) = UNK_TYPE
mutability(T::UnionAll) = mutability(T{T.var.ub})
mutability(::Type{String}) = IMM_TYPE
mutability(::Type{Symbol}) = IMM_TYPE
# This one causes problems:
mutability(::Type{Union{A,B}}) where {A,B} = begin
    let mA=mutability(A), mB=mutability(B)
        if mA === UNK_TYPE || mB === UNK_TYPE || mA !== mB
            return UNK_TYPE
        else
            return mA
        end
    end
end
```

If all of these methods but the last are defined, then the `mutability` function works as I expect with the one exception of the `Union{A,B}` types, which are always marked as unknown. However, if the last method is defined, then it matches on types like `Int64` without even binding `B` in the function body (i.e., adding `println(A, B)` at the beginning of the method results in errors due to `B` not being defined). I can see that there is an ambiguity here in that `A <: Union{A,B}`, but how does one match on a query about a `Union` type explicitly? How do I prevent a `Type{Union{A,B}}` from matching on `Type{A}` in this kind of case?

Additionally: are there other cases that this `mutability` function mislabels?

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer that I realized since posting the question is to explicitly test for a `Union` type in the default method:

```
mutability(T::Type) = begin
    if typeof(T) !== Union
        return UNK_TYPE
    else
        let mA=mutability(T.a), mB=mutability(T.b)
            if mA === UNK_TYPE || mB === UNK_TYPE || mA !== mB
                return UNK_TYPE
            else
                return mA
            end
        end
    end
end
```

With the other methods above, this results in the following all testing correctly:

```
map(k->k=>(mutability(k), isimmtype(k)), 
    [String, Symbol, Int64,
     Dict{Int64,String}, Array, Array{Int64,1},
     Tuple, Tuple{}, Tuple{Int64,String,Symbol},
     Union{String,Symbol}, Union{String,Array}, Union{Array,Dict}])
```

> # 12-element Array{Pair,1}:
>      #                      String => (Immutable(), true)
>      #                      Symbol => (Immutable(), true)
>      #                       Int64 => (Immutable(), true)
>      #          Dict{Int64,String} => (Mutable(), false)
>      #                       Array => (Mutable(), false)
>      #              Array{Int64,1} => (Mutable(), false)
>      #                       Tuple => (UnknownMutability(), false)
>      #                     Tuple{} => (Immutable(), true)
>      #  Tuple{Int64,String,Symbol} => (Immutable(), true)
>      #       Union{String, Symbol} => (Immutable(), true)
>      #        Union{String, Array} => (UnknownMutability(), false)
>      #          Union{Dict, Array} => (Mutable(), false)
>      #

All of this looks correct to me. However, I'd still like to know if there are other solutions that explicitly match on `Union` and if there are other instances where these functions fail to detect mutability correctly!

Comment: you may be interested in https://github.com/RelationalAI-oss/IsPurelyImmutable.jl

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do not care that `struct` types would require an explicit definition for `isimmtype(::Type{TheStructType})`, this works:

```
isimmtype(x::Type) = throw(ErrorException("isimmtype($x) is not defined"))

function isimmtype(::Type{T}) where {T}
  if !T.isconcretetype
    throw(DomainError("Abstract types are neither immutable nor mutable"))
  else
    return !T.mutable
  end
end

isimmtype(::Type{Symbol}) = true
isimmtype(::Type{String}) = true

function isimmtype(x::Union)
    return all(isimmtype, Base.uniontypes(x))
end

isimmtype(x::UnionAll) = isimmtype(x{x.var.ub})
```